# Zero distance between a closed set and a bounded closed set which are disjoint in a metric space

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

I've known that the distance between a compact set and a closed set is zero if and only if they are not disjoint, and I can also find counterexamples in which two disjoint closed set has zero distance.

But how about a closed set and a bounded closed set? Does there exist a closed set and a bounded closed set with zero distance between them, and they are disjoint? The counterexample should not be found in Euclidean spaces though.

Comment: Doesn't it depend on the metric? For example, using the standard bounded metric $\overline{d} = \min(d,1)$, every set in $\mathbb{R}^n$ is bounded, and the topologies generated by $d$ and $\overline{d}$ are the same.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Let $X = \{\frac{1}{n} : n\in\mathbb{N}\}$ with Euclidean metric, $A = \{\frac{1}{2n} : n\in\mathbb{N}\}$ and $B = X\setminus A$.

Then $A, B$ are closed, bounded, disjoint, and $d(A, B) = 0$.

---

It fails even if $X$ is complete:

Let $X = \ell^\infty$ and $(e_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ be defined as $e_n(i) = 1$ if $i = n$ and $0$ otherwise. Take $A = \{e_n : n\in\mathbb{N}\}$ and $B = \{(1+\frac{1}{n})e_n : n\in\mathbb{N}\}$.

Then $A, B$ are closed, bounded, disjoint and again $d(A, B) = 0$.

Comment: Great! So completeness + boundedness is not enough, and if we ask for _total boundedness_, that (plus closedness) is the same as compactness.

Answer (score 7):

In a similar spirit as Jakobian's answer, let $A=[-1,0)$, $B=(0,1]$, and $X=A \cup B$. Both $A$ and $B$ are bounded and **closed in $X$**, yet they have zero distance while remaining disjoint.

Comment: This calls for a question: what if we ask the space to be _complete_?

Comment: @IvanNeretin see my answer

Answer (score 5):

Take an example of two disjoint closed sets with distance zero and change the metric of the space by capping it at 1, i.e. setting the new distance of two points to be the minimum of 1 and their old distance. Since the metric is bounded, so is every set, but the induced topology will be the same as for the original metric.